# Mixed-mode Authentication asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I have read all the stack overflow posts and other blogs regarding mixed-mode authentication. I could not find a step by step implementation anywhere.

So here is my scenario. I have developed asp.net MVC 4.5 and asp.net identity 2.0 for individual user accounts. Some of our clients use active directory to authenticate their users whereas others use individual user accounts. Also, those that use active Directory can also remotely access the web portal and in that case authentication would be from database(Form Authentication/individual user account authentication).

### My findings so far

1. create another web application. If this client does not use "active Directory", then redirect to login screen, else, authenticate from active directory (but how?)
2. Some of the links show that there is no need to create another web application like

   - [Mixed mode authentication with OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027753/mixed-mode-authentication-with-owin)
   - [ASP.NET Identity + Windows Authentication (Mix mode - Forms + Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398991/asp-net-identity-windows-authentication-mix-mode-forms-windows)
   - [ASP.NET MVC and mixed mode authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432845/asp-net-mvc-and-mixed-mode-authentication)

Truly confused as to what to do and how to do..most solutions seem vague and general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create a second web application. 
Owin is designed to let you use all available providers (such as, Windows authentication and form-based authentication) given that you enable them in IIS.

Briefly, you have to

- Enable Anonymous and Windows authentication on IIS - Authentication
  (with server or site scope as it best fits to you)
- Anonymous authentication - Edit - Use Application Pool Identity

I recently implemented just this kind of authentication on an MVC project and it works like a charm. I suggest you to read this post https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth it's been really helpful to me.